# rails-api is installing rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api

I am building an Rails API-only application.

When I run from the command line this:

```
rails-api new myapp -T -d postgresql
```

I see this in the Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
gem 'rails-api'
gem 'spring', :group => :development
gem 'pg'
```

Rails 4.2 in installed on the system, but is it possible to install rails-api without automatically installing rails?

Comment: `rails-api` without `rails`, how do you imagine that? What are you really want to do?

Comment: I thought rails-api was the components only to serve an api ... not the whole rails stack with views etc. Is that incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partially you a right, `rails-api` has dependency to `railties` (not `rails`, my mistake), but `railties` is a core of `rails`.

So, you really can remove line `gem 'rails', '4.2.0'` from Gemfile and run server (because it part of `railties`).

I think `rails` gem here because `railties` has [generator of Rails applications](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app) and `rails-api` used it. But generated application by default has dependencies to such components of Rails as `active_record`, `active_mailer`, etc. So, `rails-api` just leave dependency to `rails` because otherwise it must remove all these dependencies from generated application.

Answer (score 1):

Install Rails 5 in your system using below command:

```
gem install rails -v 5
```

then create new rails API project below command:

```
rails new project_name --api -d postgresql
```